# Mac OS Excel Office 365: VBA for copying/deleting a row and pasting it to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, macos, office365

I'm not very clever with coding and I have a work project to do with Excel (Mac OS Office 365 version). I have some code here from VBA:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim Check As Range, r As Long, lastrow2 As Long, lastrow As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   lastrow = Worksheets("Case Management").UsedRange.Rows.Count
   For r = lastrow To 2 Step -1
   If Worksheets("Case Management").Range("AA" & r).Value = "RTW" Or 
   Worksheets("Case Management").Range("AA" & r).Value = "Out of area" Or 
   Worksheets("Case Management").Range("AA" & r).Value = "Condition 3" 
   Then
   Worksheets("Case Management").Rows(r).Cut 
   Destination:=Worksheets("from caseload").Range("A" & 
   Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)

End If
Next r

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

So what happens is that it works on any condition set out after I pressed it. But if I filled 3 rows it copies to one specific row as I show in the pictures.

1) I fill out the condition with RTW on first sheet x3 times for show
[First Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOK9C.png)

2) This is sheet two before button has been pressed
[Second Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7iB7.png)

3) When I press button on sheet 1 it looks likes this, so far so good
[Third Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyVGh.png)

4) This should not look like that, there should be 3 rows stacked but that is not the case :( 
[Fourth Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3rxH.png)

BTW the titles are on row 4.

Please help, I looked at similar articles on stack overflow but I cannot figure out the problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. The main problem that you had was that you weren't doing anything to duplicate that singe row you were cutting from `'Case Management'`. To solve that, I added `ws2.rows(lastRow2).copy Destination:=ws2.rows(lastRow2).Resize(3)` which resizes the newly pasted row to be copied 2 more times.

I also created some extra variables to clean up the way that the code looks. Notably, I added worksheet variables so that you can specify each worksheet much more simply, and I also added `val`, which stores the value at `ws1.Range("AA" & r)`. Lastly (and this is personal preference), I like to have the variables dim'ed near the location they are used, so I separated them and declare each variable essentially above where it's used.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Button1_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo ErrClose

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = sheets("Case Management")

    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = sheets("from caseload")

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws1.UsedRange.rows.count

    Dim r As Long
    For r = lastRow To 2 Step -1

        Dim val As String
        val = ws1.Range("AA" & r).Value2

        If val = "RTW" Or val = "Out of area" Or val = "Condition 3" Then
            Dim lastRow2 As Long
            lastRow2 = ws2.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp)

            ws1.rows(r).Cut Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & lastRow2)
            ws2.rows(lastRow2).copy Destination:=ws2.rows(lastRow2).Resize(3)
        End If

    Next r

ErrClose:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I am grateful for your reply. I have tried the code and it didn't work unfortunately. The button just does nothing, but I am looking into it at the moment.

Comment: @SaifAhmed Could you check to see if manually running the code does the operations as you expect so that we can see if the problem is the button or something else instead?

Answer (score 0):

If Marcucciboy is correct, change the code this way.

```
lastRow2 = ws2.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
```